# VBA macro that loops through changing sheet names

Tags: vba, excel, loops

So we have an instrument that generates a bunch of data but names the sheets effectively randomly.  I have the easy commands to go copy, paste and sort the respective text on the excel sheets but my problem is I can't figure out how to make the list of sheets that I generate loop through all those sheets while not specifying the name in the beginning..I don't want it to loop through all sheets because I need it to overlook the first sheet...

I'm getting an error 424 Object Req'd error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So I set all of my integers and variables

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim compoundname As Range
Dim compoundtype As Range
Dim compoundrng As Range
x = 1
y = 3
a = 3
b = 2
```

y,a,b are all associated with my settings omitted from the last part.

So here I tell it that I want compound name to be the range only on the active sheet, which I think is my **actual problem?**

```
Set compoundname = Workbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3")

Set compoundrng = Sheets("AllSheets").Range("A3:A100")
```

And after I've added all the sheets to the workbook, I have the loop for the names that store on the "AllSheets" worksheet

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    Sheets("AllSheets").Cells(x, 1) = ws.Name
    x = x + 1
Next ws
```

Then we have to tell it to access that list:

```
For Each compoundtype In compoundrng.Cells
```

copy, paste and sort my info here

```
Next compoundtype
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error. My guess is probably the line `Set compoundname = Workbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3")`. Try changing it to `Set compoundname = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3")`

Comment: That does resolve my 424 error but gives me an #9 error  on `Set compoundrng = Sheets("AllSheets").Range("A3:A100")`  Unsure why Though

Comment: It gives me the #9 error when i don't have the sheet in my Workbook. Are you sure there is a sheet named `AllSheets` in your workbook.

Comment: Surely you should just been looping through each sheet. Check the name of the sheet, If its not the "AllSheets" sheet then run your code...No need to store the names and loop over them later.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do something like

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    if(ws.Name <> 'YourFirstSheetName') Then
         'copy, paste and sort info here.
    end if
Next ws
```

Edit: Updated for your comment.
If you don't care about cell formatting then don't use the copy/paste command. Just set the cell equal to the value of the other cell. That way you don't have to play around with clipboard or active sheets/cells, etc.

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer

    Set ws = Worksheets("Quant Sheet")
    y = 3

    Worksheets("Quant Sheet").Activate
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If (ws.Name <> "Quant Sheet") Then
            Sheets("Quant Sheet").Cells(y, 1) = ws.Range("A3")
            y = y + 1
        End If
    Next ws
```

Comment: I think this makes a lot of sense but could you give me a bit of insight on why I'm seeing a 1004 error on the following? 
`Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Set ws = Worksheets("Quant Sheet")

y = 3

Worksheets("Quant Sheet").Activate
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If (ws.Name <> "Quant Sheet") Then
       
       ws.Range("A3").Select
       Selection.Copy
       Sheets("Quant Sheet").Select
       Cells(y, 1).Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste
       y = y + 1
        
  
    End If
    
Next ws`